# Use ISNULL or "LIKE"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which takes in a few parameters which could be NULL or maybe not.

I can use the ISNULL option if I have a clear value for a parameter, but if I want to use a "LIKE" instead of null I'm not sure how to do it. See below:

Parameters are:

```
@org_id as int,
@deleted as bit = NULL,
@firstname as char = NULL,
@lastname as char = NULL
```

Select statement is:

```
select user_id, firstname,lastname,firstname +' ' + lastname as fullname, email, phone,     is_tech, is_admin,is_cust
from users 
where users.org_id=@org_id and is_tech=1 and delete_flag=ISNULL(@deleted,delete_flag)
order by lastname,firstname asc
```

If the firstname and lastname params are not null, but are instead a character e.g."J" ,how can I write something similar to the delete_flag clause ..and firstname like 'J%' but if not use null?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
WHERE field LIKE @param OR @param IS NULL
```

Comment: Make sure you put parens around the two parts when you have more than just what is above.

Comment: Hmmm..doesn't appear to be working with parens also..where users.org_id='at'org_id and is_tech=1 and delete_flag=ISNULL('at'deleted,delete_flag) and (firstname LIKE 'at'firstname or 'at'firstname is null)....I execute the SP and only pass in the org_id it works, but when I pass in e.g. "D" as the firstname nothing appears, and I know there is a user with a firstname beginning with "D"

Comment: @thegunner What doesn't work? Show query, if possible on http://sqlfiddle.com with test data.

Comment: Depending on how your @param is constructed you may need to embed within '%'. Example: WHERE field LIKE '%' + param + '%' OR param IS NULL

Comment: @thegunner - `like 'D'` matches 'D'.  `like 'D%'` matches any string starting with 'D'.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.105).aspx) for patterns.  You can either pass the pattern as a parameter with the wildcards included, or add the wildcards in the query.

Comment: @thegunner Pass `'D%'` instead of `'D'`.